# How to remove duplicate entries from multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays

In the below array `linked_article_id` has value 3 two times but I want to remove one entry from this array (i.e I want only one unique `linked_article_id` value). I tried the below function but did't work for me:

```
$input = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $input)));
```

Array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 193 [linked_article_id] => 2 [article_id] => 1 [article_title] => Test header link [slug] => test-header-link )
        [1] => Array ( [id] => 195 [linked_article_id] => 3 [article_id] => 1 [article_title] => upload image test [slug] => upload-image-test ) 
        [2] => Array ( [id] => 197 [linked_article_id] => 4 [article_id] => 1 [article_title] => Adrenal Fatigue [slug] => arrowdesigns01-test ) 
        [3] => Array ( [id] => 200 [linked_article_id] => 9 [article_id] => 1 [article_title] => Recipe2 [slug] => recipe2 )
        [4] => Array ( [id] => 211 [linked_article_id] => 15 [article_id] => 1 [article_title] => New [slug] => new )
        [5] => Array ( [id] => 214 [linked_article_id] => 3 [article_id] => 1 [article_title] => upload image test [slug] => upload-image-test ) 
)
```

Comment: DO you understand that your array is __unreadable__?

Comment: The serialize/unserialize function does not work, because the `[id]` is different in `[1]` and `[5]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Serialization is used to compare if the entire arrays are indentical, not just one key.

You can extract the array and index (which must be unique) by `linked_article_id`:

```
$input = array_column($input, null, 'linked_article_id');
```

If you really need to re-index after (optional):

```
$input = array_values(array_column($input, null, 'linked_article_id'));
```

I don't see how anyone could be running PHP < 5.5.0 now, but just in case:

```
foreach($input as $v) {
    $result[$v['linked_article_id']] = $v;
}
```

Then if needed:

```
$result = array_values($result);
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function array_column() ?

Comment: Holy shit! You are running PHP < 5.5? Edited...Upgrade your PHP dude!